# Tkinter animation without canvas.move()

Tags: animation, tkinter

I would like to animate a canvas item WITHOUT (!!!) the canvas.move() function.

For example, I tried this:

see below:
     coords is known

```
def getCoords(i):
     ....
     return coords  #a list

for i in range(4):
     id=canvas.create_oval(getCoords(i))
     canvas.after(1000)
     canvas.delete(id)
     canvas.update()
```

It does NOT work this way.
What is wrong?  and/or
Where do I find an example?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the one function that is specifically designed to move an object?

Comment: as for what you're doing wrong: you're creating an oval, causing the program to sleep for a second _without updating the screen_, and then deleting the oval.

Comment: for a reason: animate a line with coords=[x1,y1,x2,y2] but ONLY x2 should vary. (E.g. in case of a prismatic joint in robotics).

Comment: found a way to do this:  see below     self.cv.create_line(self.x,self.y,self.x+10,self.y+10,width=10,tag="line")

        self.cv.after(100, self.moveLine)

    #------------------------------------
    def moveLine(self):

        self.cv.delete("line")
        self.x+=10
        self.y+=10
        self.cv.create_line(self.x,self.y,self.x+10,self.y+10,width=10,tag="line")
        if self.x<100:
            self.cv.after(100, self.moveLine)

Comment: Ok, so you aren't _moving_ a line, you are making it _grow_.

Comment: YES Bryan, is there a built-in function grow() similar to move()?

Answer (score 0):

You can both get and change the coordinates of a canvas object with the `coords` method.

Here's a complete example that grows an oval in the x direction by one pixel every 100ms:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def grow(canvas, item):
    (x1,y1,x2,y2) = canvas.coords(item)
    new_coords = (x1, y1, x2+1, y2)
    canvas.coords(item, new_coords)
    root.after(100, grow, canvas, item)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

item = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 100, 100, outline="black", fill="red")
grow(canvas, item)

root.mainloop()
```